# How to prevent downloading HLS (m3u8) segments files from browser

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront

I am developing web portal to deliver Videos On Demand. Its all been deployed on AWS(Amazon S3, AWS Lambda, and Amazon CloudFront)), content is on S3 and using aws cloud front services to stream video. I have used [Amazon Elastic Transcoder to transcode media files into the HLS format](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/streaming-videos-to-mobile-app-users-via-amazon-cloudfront-cdn/)(HLS segments and playlists). I am using signed url to protect download access to m3u8 files.

I am facing issues to protect downloading of segments file (.ts files), we can easily inspect these .ts files using chrome/browser inspection tools and download these segment files. These files are playable and making my video delivery solution insecure.

Please let me know how can i prevent downloading of HLS segment files?
I have already done required settings to protect direct access of media files from aws s3 bucket like given in following articles(denied public access using bucket policy etc).

Attached are the screen shot, where we can see that .ts files are downloadable by inspecting in to the browser and can be played, that I need to prevent from download or play.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/streaming-videos-to-mobile-app-users-via-amazon-cloudfront-cdn/

https://medium.com/@akshatpriyansh/securing-videos-on-your-sites-using-aws-elastictranscoder-and-hls-part-4-7ed2bc76b442

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you already have the solution? Same issue on my end :(
Please help!

Comment: Hi, any solution for this?

Comment: anyone with input on this ?

Comment: I have same problem please tell do you get any solution Thank you advance

Answer (score 0):

you could encrypt those files so whom download won't be able
to deal it without decryption key

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQ_BX1Su0qc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks alot , and  i will check the help center link , then edit  the comment .